# How to incorporate weight into linear regression in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss

I would like to know the proper procedure to execute weighted linear regression analysis. I have come across different tutorials about weighing in SPSS, but can't distinguish which is appropriate. This is a grouped analysis, Var1 and Var2 are group average and "Frequency" is the number of group members.

```
Var1     Var2     Frequency
 3.4      5.6       67
 5.6      2.5       96
 3.2      6.3       23
```

Method 1:

```
 "Data" > "weight cases by" > "Frequency" variable > then just run the linear regression
```

Method 2:

```
 "Analyze" > "Regression" > "Linear" > in the "WLS Weight" slot select "Frequency" variable.
```

Is method 1 or method 2 correct? Method 1 seems strange as the results have boosted degree of freedom (probably related to the frequency), the beta's are the same between these two methods, except degree of freedom and p-value (method 1 much lower). Or is there another, more correct, way to do weighted linear regression in SPSS?

Comment: I already showed the equivalence between the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35242076/604456). If you assume the grouped responses are independent, e.g. the 67 members that make up row 1, then Method 1 is appropriate. It is almost always a dubious assumption though.

Comment: WLS regression weights cases without affevting the degrees of freedom. In other words, cases vary by their importance only, not their frequency.

Comment: There are all kinds of statistical issues lurking here: the regressors (Var1, I presume) are averages; there is a question of how to weight averaged data in regression; there are questions about relationships among degrees of freedom when data are averaged; and there may even be questions about model construction and selection.  However, it would help to explain in English what the two different SPSS weighting options are attempting to do: that will make this question accessible to many more knowledgeable people who can answer.